# Why are aliases ignored with the `bash` command?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, alias, sudo

My operating system is Ubuntu Linux 18.04 (Xubuntu) and bash version 4.4.19

By entering the following shell commands:

- `bash -c 'foo="echo bar" && $foo'`
- `bash -c 'alias foo="echo bar" && foo'`
- `alias foo="echo bar" && foo`

I get the following output:

- `bar` (expected)
- `bash: foo: command not found` (a simple `bar` was expected)
- `bar` (expected)

The reason I ask is because I have a complicated script, which uses aliases, that I would like to execute as `root`.

I have tried:

- `sudo bash -c '/path/to/script.sh'`

But the script fails when using its own aliases.  Unfortunately, switching to root (`sudo -i`) isn't an option in my desired case scenario.

Comment: Scripts shouldn't use aliases -- they're explicitly in the POSIX sh standard as an optional interactive extension, not a core shell-language feature. Use functions instead.

Comment: If `alias foo="echo bar" && foo` produces `bar`, you have a pre-defined alias named `foo`; alias expansion in that line occurs *before* the `alias` command ever runs.

Comment: Huh. I need to correct myself a bit: As of Issue 7 (POSIX.1-2017), aliases have moved from the User Portability extensions into the POSIX sh baseline spec. Nonetheless, they're very much a newcomer to the spec, whereas functions have been in the core specification since initial publication (in 1992).

Comment: lol chepner, you're right.

Comment: Hopefully aliases will mature.

Comment: @Charlie, ...I'm not sure they're ever going to mature *into a replacement for functions* -- the whole thing that gives aliases any kind of separate utility is their status as a syntax-unaware prefix substitution facility. Makes them inappropriate for 99% of use cases, but in the other 1%, a function is unusable but an alias works; if they "matured" into something effectively equivalent to a function, then would would the point of having them at all be?

Comment: ...as an example of one of those rare corner cases where an alias does something a function can't, consider `alias DEBUG=":; #"` in https://github.com/niieani/bash-oo-framework/blob/master/lib/oo-bootstrap.sh (aside: I don't recommend that project, or that code style, to anyone; linked here only as an example). With that alias, `DEBUG "$(...)"` doesn't run at all, not even run-and-discard-its-result -- you can't do that with a function, since a function (like every other command) has its arguments evaluated before invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Aliases are enabled by default only in *interactive* shells. When you start a shell with `bash -c '...'`, it is not interactive.

Use functions instead: `bash -c 'foo() { echo bar; } && foo'` works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add functions as an example.  Thanks for your answer, however, since this is an exact duplicated question I will delete this thread...sorry.

Comment: Nevermind, it won't let me delete it.